# Python Pass List to CGI

Tags: python, cgi

In Python CGI, is it possible pass "Python list" as hidden text input field ?
How can I retrieve values using cgi form later ?

Thanks for help.

```
def testinput2(answer):
    #answer=['a','b','a','a','a']#according to abc1 statefile
        fin = file("2.map", "r")

        for line in fin.readlines():
            fun.append(line.strip().split(','))
        fin.close()
        print "<br>Action Traversal\t", answer
    for id,val in enumerate(answer):
        if id < 1:
                    first(fun,val)
                else:
                    secondandon(fun,val)


        print "<br><FORM ACTION=\"/cgi-bin/bul.py\" METHOD=\"POST\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"nxtans\" value=\"%s"%answer,"\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"nxtv\" value=\"\"><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=\"Next State Click\"></FORM><br><br>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML elements only support one value per an `input` element and know nothing of Python lists.

If you want to save a list of values in html, you should create list of hidden HTML inputs, each with the same `name` attribute.

You can later get the list of values with `form.getvalue(key)`, where the `key` is the value of the `name` attribute.